# Web Apache reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, apache, webserver, cloudflare

I have set up an web server with Apache2, cloudflare and nodejs.
I set up a reverse proxy to proxy my webserver and I got an error 524.
I searched a solution for it but didn’t found.
May you help me solve it ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It was because the proxy of cloudflare.
Solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).